# Multiple inner joins in a single statement versus pairwise joins

Tags: sql, db2, inner-join

I was given someone else's code that joins 9 (!) tables - I've used it with no problem in the past, but now all the tables have grown over time so that I'm getting weird space errors.

I got advice to break up the joins and do multiple pairwise joins.  Should be simple since all the joins are inner and everything I reads says order should make no difference in this case - but I'm getting a different number of cases than I should.  Without giving any specific very complicated example, what are some possible reasons for this?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by pairwise joins.

Comment: Joining 9 tables is not a lot.

Comment: What do you mean by "weird space errors"?

Comment: To me, joining 9 tables in a single statement is a lot!  Pairwise may have been imprecise - I mean joining two tables then joining that result to another table, then that result to another table.  Obviously they are ordered to the degree that the necessary key is available at each point.

Comment: Here's the error - tried to get more space but I'm at my max: ERROR: Write to WORK._tf0014.UTILITY failed. File is full and may be damaged.
NOTE: Error was encountered during utility-file processing. You may be able to execute the SQL statement successfully if you 
      allocate more space to the WORK library.
ERROR: There is not enough WORK disk space to store the results of an internal sorting phase.
ERROR: An error has occurred.

Comment: I don't think we can fix this without seeing the actual code.  I expect the best way to fix this is allocate more space the WORK db.

Comment: Without seeing your code we cannot spot the bug. You made a mistake while refactoring (it is no longer a refactoring...).

Comment: This does not look like a DB2 error at all (if your DB2 server is on Unix -- which one, by the way? -- as you say).

Answer (score 0):

> To me, joining 9 tables in a single statement is a lot! Pairwise may
>   have been imprecise - I mean joining two tables then joining that
>   result to another table, then that result to another table. Obviously
>   they are ordered to the degree that the necessary key is available at
>   each point.

This is not obvious to me.  In fact, it is not true.  **MOST** SQL platforms (and you still have not said which one you are using) compile SQL statements and form an execution plan.  That plan will optimize and move around when joins are executed.  On many systems that run in parallel they will execute the joins at the same time.

The way to understand the "order" of the statements is to look at the execution plan.

The way to control the order (on many systems) is to use a CTE.  Something like this:

```
WITH subsetofbigtable AS
(
   SELECT *
   FROM reallybigtable
   WHERE date = '2014-01-01'
)
SELECT *
FROM subsetofbigtable
JOIN anothertable1 ...
JOIN anothertable2 ...
JOIN anothertable3 ...
JOIN anothertable4 ...
JOIN anothertable5 ...
```

You can also chain CTEs to "order" joins:

```
WITH subsetofbigtable AS
(
   SELECT *
   FROM reallybigtable
   WHERE date = '2014-01-01'
), chain1 AS
(
   SELECT *
   FROM subsetofbigtable
   JOIN anothertable1 ...
), chain2 AS
(
   SELECT *
   FROM chain1
   JOIN anothertable2 ...
)
SELECT *
FROM chain2
JOIN anothertable3 ...
JOIN anothertable4 ...
JOIN anothertable5 ...
```

Comment: The platform is UNIX.  I understand that optimization occurs within a single statement so that multiple joins would be optimized - even so, I have space issues.  So when I attempt to break the joins down and use multiple statements I can only join whatever tables I have keys for at that point.

Comment: @user3791254 - UNIX.. nice.  But not helpful.  Are you using DB2, Oracle, mysql?  What is your **SQL** platform.

Comment: DB2...not familiar with "chaining"

Comment: @user3791254 - Well there is an example right there for you to use.  But you should just expand the space for the work area.  DB2 should have no problem with 9 joins.  (As an example I'm running 10-20 queries on it every minute with 20-30 joins each against tables with 100s of millions of rows.)

Comment: Well, I don't have those permissions to expand beyond what I've done, thus the advice to break up my single statement.  My tables have hundreds of millions of rows too, but apparently the system I'm working on doesn't have your capabilities.  So if you were to imagine that I don't have the option to expand my space, is chaining going to be more efficient in running this or is it just elegant in appearance?

Comment: @user3791254 - if formulated right it is going to be more efficient.  Using this technique is one way I've optimized performance here.  Filter on the biggest table first and then use the results to join to the other tables.  I'm assuming you have "good" indexes since techniques and knowledge on index creation is easy to find.  If you haven't looked into that side of optimization that might help fix your issues.

Comment: @user3791254 - oh, one point about CTEs and using them to chain joins.... DB2 will make use of memory when using CTEs (as op. to SQL Server which might write them to a temporary table).  If your memory is tight you might run into issues with a CTE too.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up - I'm going to throw in some filters as the original code pretty much grabbed everything and that's just not gonna fly any more.